# Wordpress screwing up PHP Session and form validation token not matching

Tags: php, session

For some reason when it generates a token it stores another token in the session and it is a completely random token.

Here is my code for the Token class -

```
class Token {

protected static $token;

public static function generate() {
    if(!self::$token){
    self::$token = md5(uniqid());
    }
    return Session::put(Config::get('session/token_name'), self::$token);
}


public static function check($token) {
    $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name');

    if(Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)) {
        Session::delete($tokenName);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

And here is my code from my Session class -

```
class Session {
public static function exists($name) {
    return (isset($_SESSION[$name])) ? true : false;
}

public static function get($name) {
    return $_SESSION[$name];
}

public static function put($name, $value) {
    return $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
}

public static function delete($name) {
    if(self::exists($name)) {
        unset($_SESSION[$name]);
    }
}

public static function flash($name, $string = null) {
    if(self::exists($name)) {
        $session = self::get($name);
        self::delete($name);
        return $session;
    } else if ($string) {
        self::put($name, $string);
    }
}
}
```

`Config::get('session/token_name')` just returns `'token'`

No where else am I generating a new token, and it wouldn't matter anyways as it will just return one token because of the static variable.

Why is WordPress doing this?

Please help I have been trying to get this to work for over 10 straight hours!

Comment: Check if you have `favicon.ico`, for example chrome always tries to download that file if it is not available, and this can delete your token...

Comment: Where is the `session_start()` in your code?

Comment: @inf3rno it is in the index.php before WordPress even loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the generate function -

```
public static function generate() {
    if(!Session::get(Config::get('session/token_name'))){
    return Session::put(Config::get('session/token_name'), md5(mt_rand())); 
    }
    else{
    return Session::put(Config::get('session/token_name'), Session::get(Config::get('session/token_name')));
    }
}
```

This ensures that you only create one for each session.